# Program design of a timetable creator

Tags: python, design-patterns

For fun, I want to write a timetable creator in python for schools. I.e. a program where schools can input their rooms, teachers, classes and subjects and some preferences and which will output a timetable for each class/teacher/room. I don't have a problem with the logic behind this (because that is the part I am most interested in), but I do have a problem with the design (due to inexperience in writing something big from scratch).

So assume I have a list of rooms (101, 102, ...), a list of teachers (Mr A, Mrs B, ...), a list of subjects (math, english, ...) and a list of classes (5, 6, ...).

Now some rooms are better suited for different subjects (like 101 is good for math & english, but geography must be in 102, if possible). Of course, every teacher has a certain set of subjects he teaches.

Also, the classes are parted in different groups. I.e. class year 5 is parted in 5-a and 5-b for all subjects except sports (where it may be 5-groupX and 5-groupY) and another subject, where it may be 5-group1, 5-group2 and 5-group3.

It would be nice if someone could give me some advice on how to efficiently save this data / design my classes, so I can write some nice code.

My first guess would be something like (pseude code):

```
class Room:
    string name     # e.g. r102.name = "102"
    int id          # that should be unique?

class Subject:
    string name     
    int id          
    map RoomPref    # like geography.Roompref[r102.id] = 1.0 
                    # or math.Roompref[r101.id] = 0.75 

class Teacher:  
    list Subjects   # like MrsB.Subjects = {geography.id, math.id}
```

etc, etc, but I am not sure if this approach is good and leads to nice code. Especially all the different interconnections pose a problem to me.  (Is assigning different IDs a good solution?)

Advice and/or reading material is welcome.

Comment: This is basically impossible to answer properly. It seems you're looking at an NP-Complete combinatorial problem. Your concern should probably be on the heuristic that you're going to use to solve this. Appraising/scoring an interim solution and storing that state is far more complex; without knowing your proposed heuristic, the data structure would be tough to recommend. Certainly you need pools of those three items, so using classes isn't a bad way to define the individual units in your problem... if they're amenable to your cost function.

Comment: Write something small that works.  Add on to it. Add some more. Realize you did some silly things.  Refactor the code so it is less silly.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

One difficult part of this problem is that there are numerous relations that make up a schedule. I would think very carefully about how a teacher T teaches a class and she teaches it in room X at 1:30 pm.

For example, in your program, you may want to know when room X is available. To do this, you will want to check your data structures and find room X, then search the list of times that room X is either free or occupied. HOWEVER, in another case, you may want to know whether or not Teacher J teaches math. So you would do a similar lookup and search all the classes that Teacher J teaches.

So my advice is this: you will want to avoid what may initially seem like the easiest option to create a data structure where you create an organization of time slots and then assign teachers and classes to those times. You would likely make quick progress at first, but eventually run into trouble when you realize how difficult it is to use a structure of Class objects to represent a set of relationships.

Instead, try starting with a relational database like mysql. Use references to other tables in order to link data from one table to another instead of writing all the code yourself. There's no need to reinvent the wheel here and try to write a complex class structure to represent what are essentially simple (though possibly highly interconnected) relationships.

Comment: I disagree on the database side; everything in memory. This is not just a relational issue, it seems like a classic timetabling problem. As such, only a heuristic can be used to approach a solution... absolute relationships should be avoided. In other words, you must generate interim solutions in which some kind of impossibility is accepted but penalised, and this should not be I/O bound - a "dumb" approach will brute force with many 1000's answers, a smart one will _try_ to be selective.

Comment: I think I agree with your line of thinking more than you believe. I only propose a database to cut down on the work load. I would not advocate for absolute and permanent relationships at all. Instead, there would need to be a field for time in most tables. So when a teacher has a class, you can say it is in room x at time T.

I think an important question here is that of scale. If you want to allow other people to use your application, keeping this all in memory will become quite cumbersome.

Comment: It's quite possible that we're on the same page because I agreed otherwise :) I don't think a realistic problem of this type would exceed memory size, I tackle vehicle routing problems in memory every day. But can you imagine how many millions of queries would be needed for a decent sized problem... every choice needs to query DB to get a pool of resources? I'd rather try pool the units in memory somehow if I could.